# "ПіцЕрія" чи "ПіцерІя"?

Tags: наголос

Як правильно ставити наголос у слові піцерія
"піцЕрія" чи "піцерІя"?

Посилання на обговорення:
https://www.facebook.com/654887197880807/posts/2305225662846944/

Маю певні сумніви щодо наведеного варіанта на зображенні.

[image]

Comment: Де спроби власноруч розібрати власного питаньа?

Comment: Цікаво було б дізнатись, чому саме піцЕрія, це якесь правило притаманне українській мові? Самих лише словників тут мало.

Comment: @Sasha таке обґрунтування було б доречною частиною відповіді.

Comment: Це було запитання. Додав знак питання у заголовку. Сумніви викликао обговорення в коментарях до зображення у фб. Тому й написав сюди, бо цей ресурс є більш конструктивнішим для обговорення таких питань. Дякую за зауваження та відпоаіді

Comment: Змінив текст, щоб було більш зрозуміліше

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Орфографічний словник української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/35/53407/153525.html)

> піце́рія  іменник жіночого роду

[ВТССУМ](https://www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F)

> піце́рія
> -ї, ж. Закусочна, в якій готують та подають піцу.

[Вільний тлумачний словник](http://sum.in.ua/f/picerija)

> піце́рі́я -ї, жін. Заклад харчування, у якому головним чином готують
> піцу.

Правильно наголос піцЕрія

Answer (score 2):

У словниках дивина:

- [ABBYY Lingvo тлумачний](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F) (на основі «ВТССУМ» В. Бусела) — *піц**е́**рія*;
  [ABBYY Lingvo українсько-російський](//www.lingvolive.com/ru-ru/translate/uk-ru/%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F) (імовірно, на основі рос.-укр. В. Бусела) — *піцер**і́**я*;
  «Великий орфографічний словник сучасної української мови» В. Бусела — *піц**е́**рія*.
- [«Словники України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) — *піц**е́**рія*.
- [«Граматичний словник української мови» від MOVA.info](http://www.mova.info/grmasl.aspx) — *піцер**і́**я*.

Загалом, у російській і українській мові, мені здається, тенденція однакова: настаріші й найконсервативніші словники дають лише наголос на *-е-*, але оскільки [оригінальний італійський наголос саме на *-і-*](//it.wiktionary.org/wiki/pizzeria#Pronuncia) (і в найпоширеніших світових мовах, наприклад [англійській](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pizzeria#Pronunciation), теж наголос на *-і-*), то не дивно, що маємо тенденцію до перенесення наголосу на *-і-*. Тому я особисто підтримую [позицію, висловлену у «Вільному тлумачному словнику»](http://sum.in.ua/f/picerija) (що обидва наголоси правильні — *піц**е́**р**і́**я*), хоч цей словник і не є офіційно виданим (а є спробою авторів порталу sum.in.ua самотужки заповнити прогалини в «Словнику української мови» в 11 томах).

Але якщо говорити про те, який усе-таки наголос «найправильніший», то більшість джерел усе-таки за *піц**е́**рія*. До ненаведених у моїй відповіді джерел можна додати [урок № 62 від Олександра Авраменка](http://%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE.%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80/tele-radio-lessons/12/201-urok-62.html) і [наведену вже в запитанні сторінку «Мова — ДНК нації»](//www.facebook.com/mova.ukr/photos/a.654924277877099/2305223939513783/).

Чому незважаючи на те, що в оригінальному італійському слові наголос на *-і-*, в українській мові спочатку зафіксувався наголос на *-е-*? Я не знаю, але припускаю, що, по-перше, аналогічно до більшості слів на *-ія* (*куліна́рія* (так, за словниками саме так), *орфое́пія*, *флюорогра́фія* тощо), а по-друге, подібно до російської мови. Хоча і в українській, і в російській мові є також слова на *-ія* (рос. *-ия*) з наголосом на *-і-* (рос. *-и-*), наприклад *буржуазі́я* (рос. *буржуази́я*), але рідко.